# Neomodel cypher query missing positional argument

Tags: python, cypher, neomodel

I'm trying to query my Employee model with `.cypher` within my Django view. I've used this query elsewhere, so I know that part works.

```
query_string = "MATCH (n)-[r:REPORTS_TO|BRANCH_OF|OVERSEEN_BY]->() RETURN n, r"

query_results = Employee.cypher(
    self = Employee, 
    query = query_string, 
    params = None)

***   ERROR _pre_action_check() 
      missing 1 required positional argument: 'action'
```

> This error points to line 204 here:
>
> [https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neomodel/blob/master/neomodel/core.py](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neomodel/blob/master/neomodel/core.py#L204)

---

I've tried:

- action=cypher
- action='cypher'
- self=neomodel
- self=django-neomodel
- self=cypher

Also, if I try to follow the documentation by defining the cypher call within the model and then calling it in the view... I still get the same error

> https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cypher.html

---

**UPDATE:**
full trace here https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPs3B.jpg

Comment: It is a *positional* parameter.

Comment: hmm. so something to do with `results, columns = self.cypher` ? thought that looked strange in the documentation

Comment: Can we see the entire Traceback?

Comment: @JacobIRR updated with trace!

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax Is Employee a Class object? It looks like it is reading your query string as the self argument because Employee isn't an instance.

Comment: @Tezra Yes. Employee is a class in the model.

Comment: Ok, so your query string is being read as the self argument, and it is still waiting for the query string. You need to create an instance of Employee to call .cypher on. I don't know how to help further, but sounds like @JacobIRR knows how to take it from here. (unless you know already how to create the instance object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you're calling this method with three positional args seems wrong.

The method signature is:

```
def cypher(self, query, params=None):
```

-`self` is already provided by your `Employee.` prefix. (WRONG, see below)

-`query` should just be passed in as positional `query_string` argument

-`params=None` is simply passing the default value, which is useless.

Have you tried `Employee.cypher(query_string)` ?

Based on what Tezra said, you need an instance of Employee:

```
employee = Employee()
```

Then call `employee.cypher(query_string)`

Comment: yes that was the first thing i tried. i can reply after lunch with the error it produces

Comment: Sounds good - I'd like to see that error since it at least comes from using the method as expected.

Comment: `cypher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'` in response to Employee.cypher(query_string)

Comment: Can you share the full trace for that example? The only way I get `cypher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'` is to call `cypher` with no arguments at all.

Comment: @JacobIRR It looks like Employee is the class, not the instance, so the query is being read as the self argument... I'm not familiar with the python driver so I don't know how to create an instance of self though (I'm guessing that is the asnwer).

Comment: @Tezra @JacobIRR the instance did it! thank you! working on new error "Employee.cypher() attempted on unsaved node" which im pretty sure is because im using uid, not id attributes `if not hasattr(self, 'id'):
            raise ValueError("{}.{}() attempted on unsaved node".format(
                self.__class__.__name__, action))`

Comment: merp. no it looks like they have id's too `'id': 68}>,` so maybe it's the instance.

Comment: looks like Employee() is creating a new resource `<Employee: {'uid': '115ae498a5024829bd0f6f3b4148955e', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 18,` ... with none for all fields